# jsx remove parent according to size

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Says I have a DOM like this

```
<div className="parent">
   <div>child 1</div>
   <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

and if it's mobile, I want to make the DOM become

```
   <div>child 1</div>
   <div>child 2</div>
```

Can I do it with just css? I guess I have to use conditional expression in jsx? What library to use to check media query in jsx?

Comment: No, you can’t do that in plain CSS. But you might have a desktop and mobile version and hide one based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you will need to use jsx for this**

And you have (at least i can think of) two approaches:

- you can use vanila JS like so:

> `const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;`

and then to use that value based on your needs to render jsx conditionaly.

- or you can use something like react-responsive:

> `npm install react-responsive --save`

then in your app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

const Example = () => {
  // you can add whatever widths you want

  const isDesktopOrLaptop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-width: 1224px)'
  })

  const isTabletOrMobile = useMediaQuery({ 
    query: '(max-width: 1224px)' 
  })

  return (
    <div>
      // your conditional jsx here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here are the ref:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth